# How to troubleshoot aptitude / dpkg when installs hang up

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, configuration

I am trying to set up servers using [LXD containers](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/lxd) and **Ubuntu/Debian images**, but often run into installation problems with **aptitude**. In this example I want to set up a [cozy server](https://cozy.io/en/).

Aptitude completely hangs with the line `Setting up <package> (version) ...`, for instance

```
Setting up rsync (3.1.1-3) ... 
Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out
```

and when I abort it and restart the installation, it tells me to run `dpkg --configure --all` because of an aborted installation. Makes sense. That command however again results in the same problems. Canceling the process dpkg then prints

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
rsync
supervisor
nginx-full
(and many more ...)
```

Then I though to try and install/configure the packages individually, such that I can troubleshoot problems. I entered `apt-get --configure supervisor` which gives me

```
dpkg --configure supervisor
Setting up supervisor (3.0r1-1) ...
Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory
Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory
Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory
invoke-rc.d: initscript supervisor, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package supervisor (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 supervisor
```

How do I troubleshoot from this point on? How do I figure out why the configuration is failing? As far as I can tell, some initialization is failing. I am really stuck here.